# How to CSP header URLs with specific patterns

Tags: java, security, header, content-security-policy

There are few URLs like
http://aa.bb.dd.com
http://aa.bb1.dd.com

I added the CSP whitelist url with the pattern like the below,

```
http://*.bb*.*.com
```

But I am getting an error

```
The source list for Content Security Policy directive 'script-src' contains an invalid source: 'https://*.bb*.*.com'. It will be ignored
```

How to add the pattern so that bb* (aa.bb1.dd.com, aa.bb2.dd.com etc..,) to be allowed?

Comment: gkrishna, I see that you have [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1387204/gkrishna?tab=questions) posted that weren't properly resolved (including this one). Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), then take appropriate action on all those posts to compensate your volunteer helpers for their time. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can’t.

The spec lists hosts as the following:

```
; Hosts: "example.com" / "*.example.com" / "https://*.example.com:12/path/to/file.js"
host-source = [ scheme-part "://" ] host-part [ port-part ] [ path-part ]
scheme-part = scheme
              ; scheme is defined in section 3.1 of RFC 3986.
host-part   = "*" / [ "*." ] 1*host-char *( "." 1*host-char )
host-char   = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-"
port-part   = ":" ( 1*DIGIT / "*" )
path-part   = path-abempty
              ; path-abempty is defined in section 3.3 of RFC 3986.
```

That is the host can be either a *, or begin with *.  They cannot have a * in the middle or end of it.

So you could have `*.dd.com` (but not `*.*.dd.com`).

To be honest using wildcards as you want would open security issues and defeat the point of using CSP as I could load resources from any domain just by using a subdomain with bb in it (e.g. http://www.bb.baddomain.com).

Comment: Just be aware that the above seems to be the CSP level 3 spec, which is still currently in draft status.